# Htaccess wrongly making 301 redirect

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, dynamic

I'm just trying to display css content at http://mydomain.com/dynamic_css/presets/
when user's browser loads http://mydomain.com/css/dynamic.css using the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^dynamic\.css$ http://mydomain.com/dynamic_css/presets/ [QSA,L]
```

But instead browser gets http 301 redirected to http://mydomain.com/dynamic_css/presets/

Any idea why ?

Basically, the script at http://mydomain.com/dynamic_css/presets/ shows up a CSS generated code to allow more styles control from admin settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't specify the full domain in your request. `mod_rewrite` assumes this is an external URL which can only be handled via redirect. Try the below instead.

```
RewriteRule ^dynamic\.css$ /dynamic_css/presets/ [QSA,L]
```